# Why is my Black Locust dropping spotted leaves?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, diseases

I have a Black Locust tree that has been planted for 1 year. It has full sun and as of this Spring I have watered it every other evening for 20-30 minutes.
It has grown significantly the last few months and had dozens of flowers.
We are located in eastern Washington and are currently going through a drought. Over the last week the leaves have turned yellow, have brown and green spots and are dropping from the tree. I dug down 5-6 inches in the dirt near the trunk and the dirt was damp. Not wet enough to form into a shape, but not powdery dry either.
There are no signs of Aphids, nothing abnormal looking on the bark and I'm not seeing any leaves that look like they have been eaten by bugs.
Is this a lack of or too much water situation or something fungal?